# if-else statement

Tags: c, if-statement, control-flow

My codes allows the user to enter in a score from 1 to 100, which will either tell them that the score is "Good", "OK", "Moron", or "Invalid".

But, when I compile these codes. The output has invalid in it too with the correct statement if it is more than 54.

For example :

- if I enter in 55 it will say "OK" AND "Invalid".
- if I enter in 54 it will just say "Moron".

Here are my codes:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()   
{
    int score;
    printf("Enter a Score");
    scanf("%d", &score);
    if (score >=80 && score <= 100){
        printf("Good\n",);
    }
     if (score >=55 && score <=79){
        printf("OK\n",);
    }
     if (score >=1 && score <=54){
        printf("Moron\n",);
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid\n");
    }    
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is happening because instead of using one control flow you use multiple (thus if condition is met before the last `if` control flow (`score >= 55` through `score <= 100`), `else` code from the last one is also executed). You can use `else if` branches:

```c
if (score >= 80 && score <= 100){
   printf("Good\n",);
} else if (score >= 55 && score <= 79){
   printf("OK\n",);
} else if (score >= 1 && score <= 54){
   printf("Moron\n",);
} else {
   printf("Invalid\n");
}
```

You can also use nested `if`/`else` statements, but the solution above seems less cumbersome.

Answer (score 7):

Each `if` statement is a standalone conditional statement. Your example has three groups of conditional statements:

1. `if (score >=80 && score <= 100)`
2. `if (score >=55 && score <=79)`
3. `if (score >=1 && score <=54) { ... } else { ... }`

So if `score` has the value `55`, it will match against #2 above and the `else` of #3.

One solution here would be to combine the above statements into one group. You can do this with `else if`.

e.g.

```
if (*expr*) {
    ...
} else if (*expr*) {
    ...
} else if (*expr*) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 `if-else` statements and both get executed. So you will do "something" for both of them. Walk through your code with `score=55` and you'll find the problem.

2 solutions:

1. Make the `if`s "standalone" (so only one will pass)
2. Add some `else`s to ensure only one of your branches executes.