# Why deos my else statement still trigger even when my if statement before it has already triggered why does this happen

Tags: c

Hi i am new to C i am writing a basic hangman game and when i run the code the else statement still triggers even if the if statement before it has triggered why does this happen

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int Guesses = 0;
  int Completion = 0;
  char UserGuess;
  char Word[] = "fire";

  while (Guesses < 6) {
    if (Completion == 4) {
      printf("You Won\n");
      break;
    }

    printf("Please Enter Your Guess It Can Only Be A Letter Not A Word\n");
    printf("The Word Is 4 Characters Long\n");

    scanf("%c", &UserGuess);

    if (UserGuess == 'f') {
      printf("You Guessed One Of The Letters\n");
      printf("f_ _ _\n");
      Completion++;
    }

    if (UserGuess == 'i') {
      printf("You Guessed One Of The Letters\n");
      printf("_i_ _\n");
      Completion++;
    }

    if (UserGuess == 'r') {
      printf("You Guessed One Of The Letters\n");
      printf("_ _r_ \n");
      Completion++;
    }

    if (UserGuess == 'e') {
      printf("You Guessed One Of The Letters\n");
      printf("_ _ _e\n");
      Completion++;
    }
    else {
      printf("You Guessed The Letter Wrong try again\n");
      Guesses++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably mean a string of if/else statements instead of a string of ifs

Comment: This is the same problem as here: [if-else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908213/if-else-statement)

Comment: As well as the logic problems (suppose someone guesses `f` and `i`; are you not going to show both `f` and `i` — at the moment, it looks like you'd only show the latest guessed letter), you should probably be using `" %c"` to input `UserGuess`.  That will skip white space such as newlines (and blanks and tabs)..

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `if..else`:

```
if (UserGuess == 'e') {
  printf("You Guessed One Of The Letters\n");
  printf("_ _ _e\n");
  Completion++;
}
else {
  printf("You Guessed The Letter Wrong try again\n");
  Guesses++;
}
```

This will print "You Guessed The Letter Wrong" if you enter any letter besides 'e'.

You need to add an `if..else..if` chain for all your conditions:

```
if (UserGuess == 'f') {
  printf("You Guessed One Of The Letters\n");
  printf("f_ _ _\n");
  Completion++;
} else if (UserGuess == 'i') {
  printf("You Guessed One Of The Letters\n");
  printf("_i_ _\n");
  Completion++;
} else if (UserGuess == 'r') {
  printf("You Guessed One Of The Letters\n");
  printf("_ _r_ \n");
  Completion++;
} else if (UserGuess == 'e') {
  printf("You Guessed One Of The Letters\n");
  printf("_ _ _e\n");
  Completion++;
} else {
  printf("You Guessed The Letter Wrong try again\n");
  Guesses++;
}
```

Comment: ... or a `switch`...

Comment: i tried your edit to the code but it still seems to print the else statement for some reason

Comment: @HiddenSquid, Try again; You must have changed something